# Vuetify - v-text-field

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am making an autocomplete text input, and I need the suggestion to "highlight" the rest of the current word

Let's say I have the following text: "The car is being dri"

And the suggestion list is `['driven', 'drunk', 'droids']`

Then I would want the autocomplete part to make the rest of the word, **after** the cursor to be highlighted or bold or something like this

```
The car is being dri|ven
                    ^
                cursor is still here
```

I tried finding some slot or something to manipulate the text but found nothing, any ideas how this can be done ?